# is jsonp possible in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I want to know is JSON padding 'jsonp' works in Google map API ?
In an application i have to implement google map by replacing bing map(already developed).
In below url bing uses jsonp to respond back the response

https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/37.556141,-122.287880?output=json&jsonp=LocationPane.drawLocationHistory_0_OnMap&key=SOME_KEY

I tried to prepare the url as and also tried many combination of it

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.5236,73.8478&jsonp=LocationPane.drawLocationHistory_0_OnMap&sensor=false

but its not working as it works in Bing map.
Please let me know is json padding possible in google map or is there any better way to use geocoding

Answer (score 0):

jsonp is currently not supported by the geocoding-webservice.

But you may use the geocoding-service of the JS-API to retrieve the results and pass them to the callback-function.